# Why isn't there an inquiry into the assassination of Malcolm X, given that there is solid evidence of a conspiracy by the FBI targetting him?

Tags: united-states, law, racism, civil-rights, fbi

Raymond Wood, a former NYPD undercover officer, in a death-bed confession, admitted to being part of a conspiracy to target Malcolm X. He stated that he was part of a conspiracy by the NYPD to trap two of Malcolm X's security team into a plot to blow up the Statue of Liberty, just a few days before Malcolm's assassination. In fact, he was assigned by the NYPD to surveil the Audubon Ballroom where Malcolm X was to make a speech and where he was assassinated.  This is all detailed in [an article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/history/2021/02/22/malcolm-x-assassination-letter-nypd-fbi/) by the Washington Post on the 22nd February this year.

Obviously, given the fame and influence of Malcolm X, there are plenty of conspiracy theories swirling around what actually occurred during his assassination, but without solid evidence, there is little one can say, apart from speculation. However, here we have solid, prima facie, evidence of such a conspiracy amongst the NYPD, and perhaps higher.

**Q. Why would the FBI or the NYPD feel it necessary to entrap members of Malcolm X's security detail in a crime?**

**Q. Given the solid evidence of a conspiracy why isn't there a full scale enquiry into the assassination of Malcolm X?**

Comment: Your question seems a bit broad, you might want to either split it up, or just ask one of the two questions. Though your first question seems trivial; [disrupting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COINTELPRO) the civil rights movement by any means necessary was the FBIs job; it regularly involved planting of evidence, harassment, violence, etc, with assassinations being the most drastic measures they took. The entrapment you mention doesn't seem out of the ordinary.

Comment: I took a look at some articles about this. It appears that the allegations of FBI involvement in his assassination are based on fairly new information, so perhaps that is the answer to your question. There is no publicly announced inquiry because it has been less than a month since the officer's confession was published. Eighteen days is a short time to reopen an old case, and I am not sure that there would be a public announcement so soon even if they had.

Comment: @tim: In what way is the question overly "broad"? If disrupting the civil rights movemrnt was the "FBI's job" then why is the civil rights movement seen as one of historic importance in the history of the USA?

Comment: @MoziburUllah Because the first question is about the motives behind the FBIs actions in the 60s, while the second question is about the (lack of) action by todays institutions. While loosely related, imho answers to these two questions are very different, so combining both questions into one question causes problems for answerers (either they have to ignore one question and thus write only half an answer, or they have to go through the trouble of essentially writing two answers to two separate questions)

Comment: @tim: They're hardly unrelated, as you've pointed out. Moreover, the first question is why the FBI felt it neccessary to target Malcolm X. Not everyone did, for example, he got a hige round of applause from the audience when he was debating at the Oxford Union.

Comment: @MoziburUllah People applauding an activist who wants to change the status quo is a very good reason why people who *benefit* from the status quo would want to have that activist gone. You seem to be looking at the US civil rights movement through a modern, progressive, 21st century lense, through which it looks pretty agreeable. But that was not the sentiment of that time. Otherwise the movement would not have been necessary.

Comment: @Phillip: If that was not the sentiment at the time then why did the Oxford Union give Malcolm X rapturous applause when he debated there? I'd say that the sentiment in elite circles and ordinary circles are not as hegemonic as you are making it out to be.

Comment: Uh, OK? Maybe? That seems largely irrelevant to your question, and I would point out that we are talking about a primarily American context. The hostility toward him in the US might be expected to be much greater than in Britain, and young students who had turned out specifically to see him are about as far from J. Edgar Hoover's FBI as can be.

Comment: Do you have any sources for that information that are not behind a paywall? Found one that isn't behind a paywall. https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2021/02/22/malcolm-x-family-letter-alleging-nypd-fbi-role-assassination/4542195001/

Comment: @joe W: There's the article by the Washington Post that is linked in. Although the main site is behind a paywall, this article is free to read.

Comment: When I go to the link I get a popup asking me to subscribe that blocks the screen making me unable to read the story unlike the link I provided.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah: Re movies about insignificant people, as I said, I am anything but a movie fan, but a few minutes thought comes up with "Chariots of Fire" about a couple of 1920s Olympic athletes, and "Raging Bull", about a self-destructive boxer in the 1940s.  I'm sure any movie fan could give you many more names.

Comment: @Jamesqf: Olympic athletes are relatively well-known and Jake La Motta, aka Raging Bull, was also well known enough at the time to turn his boxing career into a movie career. You could also [look](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Malcolm+X%2C+Lady+Gaga&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMalcolm%20X%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLady%20Gaga%3B%2Cc0) at Googles NGram viewer, plotting Malcom X against Lady Gaga - you can see he easily outscores her. You have heard of Lady Gaga, or is she also another insignificant celebrity nobody's heard of, including you?

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah: There's a difference between being known to fans of a particular activity, and being historically significant.  As for Lady Gaga, while I have of course seen mention of her (another beneficiary of an oddball name :-)), and inferring from context that she's some sort of pop music singer, why would I think her significant, any more than say various Kardashians and their ilk?

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah: One might also suspect, from what has been said in news reports, that the FBI and other relevant law enforcement groups are fully occupied investigating the recent coup attempt, which is arguably a higher priority than something that happened over half a century ago.

Comment: @jamesqf: The question was about fame and name recognition and the point I'm making is that he outscores Lady Gaga in the fame stakes despite all her visibility. As for significance, Malcolm X was a leader of the civil rights movement during the 60s and surely even you understand the significance of that movement  in the history of the USA.

Comment: @jamesqf: The FBI are a large enough that they can easily open a full investigation into the conspiracy around Malcolm X by the NYPD and allegedly themselves. Given his historical importance  it would be right to do so. After all, had sinilar evidence turned up about the assassination of JF Kennedy would you have said that the FBI is so "fully occupied investigating the recent coup attempt" that they couldn't investigate one of the most significant assassinations in USA history? Had you said that in public, the US public amd US media  would make mincemeat out of you.

Comment: @jamesqf: Are you prepared to say that? No, of course not.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah:  "...investigate one of the most significant assassinations in USA history"?  That's the question here: just what is all that significant about the half-century old killing of a religious cult leader?  You seem to think he was of some historical importance, but I doubt your opinion is universal.

Comment: @jamesqf: He was a civil rights leader - like I have already asked, you have heard of that?  Moreover, to think that Islam is a cult religion when it is followed by a billion or so muslims shows a significant lack of understanding of what significance means on your part.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah: I think we must be talking about two different Malcom Xs.  What he is remembered for is primarily his association with the Nation of Islam.  That was certainly a cult based on Islam, just as cults like the People's Temple https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peoples_Temple and Unification Charch (AKA "Moonies") https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Myung_Moon were cults based on Christianity.

Comment: @jamesqf: We are not talking about two different Malcolm X's. There are many denominations of Islam in Islam, just as there are many denominations of christianity, ie pentocontalism, quakers and so on. Malcoln X is well known for his advocacy of Islam as well as the civil rights of black american citizens.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah: I suppose I should know better than to try sarcasm on you.  Nor do I have time or space for an explanation of why certain groups are cults. (Simplistically, it's a good diagnostic when the group is primarily for the leader's benefit.)  I'll just try reiterating plain fact: at the time, most Americans regarded Malcolm X as a cult leader, not a civil rights leader.  I would wager that opinion stands today, at least among those who even know who he was.

Comment: @jamesqf: Malcolm X was a civil rights leader; that's not a cult - go check your history of the USA ...

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah: History?  I was there at the time :-)

Answer (score 6):

The authorities have [released](https://abc7ny.com/malcolm-x-murder-assassination-civil-rights/10357490/) these statements in response to the new evidence presented by Malcom X's family lawyers:

> Malcolm X's three daughters, along with Wood's family and high-profile Civil Rights attorney Ben Crump, are asking for the murder investigation to be re-opened in light of the new evidence. [...]
>
> Three Nation of Islam members were convicted in Malcolm X's murder. Last year the Manhattan DA began a review of those convictions after meeting with representatives of the Innocence Project.
>
> Now, with the new evidence, **the DA's office says "the review of this matter is active and ongoing."**
>
> On Monday, the FBI released a statement on the investigation.
>
> > The FBI's New York field office is aware of recent reporting regarding the circumstances surrounding Malcom X's death. Over the past several months, we have worked cooperatively with the Manhattan District Attorney's Office to assist in its review of the matter and provide relevant documents from FBI holdings. Today's FBI stands for the noble pursuit of justice, and we will continue to support the review in any way we can.
>
> The NYPD also responded on Saturday.
>
> > Several months ago, the Manhattan District Attorney initiated a review of the investigation and prosecution that resulted in two convictions for the murder of Malcom X. The NYPD has provided all available records relevant to that case to the District Attorney. The Department remains committed to assist with that review in any way.

So there is some kind of review of the case ongoing in the Manhattan DA office. The FBI and NYPD have declared their support of this effort.

Comment: Mozibur, you might notice that tim's point he was making in his comment is proven true, at least in this answer. It only details a response to one of your questions, that of what are current institutions doing now. Your two questions should properly be split up.

Answer (score 2):

At this point an answer is of historical interest, but it doesn't have a lot of immediate salience or demand a swift investigation.

Suppose that anyone actively involved in making decisions in the original plot (if there was one) was 25 years old or older at the time, i.e. born in 1940 or earlier. The youngest individual involved in now age 80 or older, and most of the senior people calling the shots in any operation like that are probably dead now.

It would be nice to get an accurate determination of what happened historically, but in and of itself, knowing something different than the current narrative doesn't change a whole lot. Malcolm X is still dead. Lots has happened to race relations and government corruption in the interim.

Comment: And I suspect that unlike for outright murder, conspiracy to deprive people of civil rights is subject to statute of limitations. Mkay, there's [actually](https://www.fbi.gov/investigate/civil-rights/federal-civil-rights-statutes) no such limitation if it results in death, but your point still stands.

Comment: Well, the allegation, as I understand it, would effectively be that the FBI conspired with at least one disaffected member of the Nation of Islam to kill him, by reducing his security and giving them a free shot. That would be murder, and likely not subject to the statute of limitations.

Comment: While the existence of compelling evidence establishing an FBI assassination conspiracy would not personally un-murder anyone, such evidence would still be very useful in establishing accountability, both exoneratively, and to help correct undue public approval for the perpetrators and their methods.

Comment: @Obie2.0 My point is that there is very likely no one left to hold accountable (in either a civil action or a criminal case) and no policies to change that haven't already been changed. It would set the historical record straight, and that isn't nothing, but that is all.